# Three line option for slider menu doen't work for one fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have created slider menu in my activity which consist of 11 option.When i click on any option it switches to its corresponding fragment.I am having problem in just one fragment.Fragment opens fine but when i click on the three line option for slider menu,menu doesn't open.This problem is not there in any other fragments as the slider menu opens fine for other fragments.I am posting the code for fragment in which problem exist.

PhotosFragment.java

```
public class PhotosFragment extends Fragment implements ActionBar.TabListener  {
    private FragmentActivity myContext;
    private ViewPager viewPager;
    private TabsPagerAdapter mAdapter;
    private ActionBar actionBar;
    // Tab titles
    private String[] tabs = { "IBL Tweets", "Fans Updates", "My Updates" };


        public PhotosFragment(){}
        @Override
        public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
            myContext=(FragmentActivity) activity;
            super.onAttach(activity);
        }


        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setHasOptionsMenu(true);
        }
        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {

            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_photos, container, false);
            viewPager = (ViewPager)rootView.findViewById(R.id.pager);
            actionBar =getActivity().getActionBar();
            mAdapter = new TabsPagerAdapter(myContext.getSupportFragmentManager());

            viewPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);
            actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(false);
            actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);        

            // Adding Tabs
            for (String tab_name : tabs) {
                actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText(tab_name)
                        .setTabListener(this));
            }

            /**
             * on swiping the viewpager make respective tab selected
             * */
            viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {

                @Override
                public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                    // on changing the page
                    // make respected tab selected
                    actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
                }

                @Override
                public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {
                }

                @Override
                public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {
                }
            });
            return rootView;
        }
        @Override
        public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
            inflater.inflate(R.menu.main2, menu);
        }



        @Override
        public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
        }



        @Override
        public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }



        @Override
        public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

    }
```

main2.xml

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_settings"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:showAsAction="never"
        android:title="@string/action_settings"/>


  <item android:id="@+id/action_search"
          android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_new_picture"
          android:title="@string/app_name"
          android:showAsAction="ifRoom"/>


</menu>
```

fragment_photos.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
</android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem should be in the line

```
actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(false);
```

it makes ActionBar icon not clickable, remove it and try again or put

```
 actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
```

instead

Comment: but now action bar navigation tabs "IBL Tweets", "Fans Updates", "My Updates" which i have added for only that fragment is visible in all fragments

Comment: once i switch to this fragment then thereafter these navigation tabs "IBL Tweets", "Fans Updates", "My Updates"  are visible in all fragments

Comment: because you activate ActionBar Tabs when you switch to that Fragment.
put         actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_STANDARD);
in onCreateView of all fragments you don't want tabs to be displayed

Comment: my app crashes if i add tht in onCreateView of other fragments..logcat shows-07-23 13:29:43.887: E/AndroidRuntime(25515):  at info.androidhive.slidingmenu.AlbumsFragment.onCreateView(AlbumsFragment.java:28)
07-23 13:29:43.887: E/AndroidRuntime(25515):  at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:829)
07-23 13:29:43.887: E/AndroidRuntime(25515):  at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1035)
07-23 13:29:43.887: E/AndroidRuntime(25515):  at android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:635)

Comment: try to put it to onCreateOptionsMenu() of fragments instead on in onCreateView()

Comment: still showing error 07-23 13:47:31.140: E/AndroidRuntime(26928): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-23 13:47:31.140: E/AndroidRuntime(26928): java.lang.NullPointerException
07-23 13:47:31.140: E/AndroidRuntime(26928):  at info.androidhive.slidingmenu.AlbumsFragment.onCreateOptionsMenu(AlbumsFragment.java:38)
07-23 13:47:31.140: E/AndroidRuntime(26928):  at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchCreateOptionsMenu(FragmentManager.java:1871)
07-23 13:47:31.140: E/AndroidRuntime(26928):  at android.app.Activity.onCreatePanelMenu(Activity.java:2489)
)

Comment: got it right now..need to add  actionBar = getActivity().getActionBar();
        actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_STANDARD); inside onCreateView()..thanks

Comment: Suppose i want to add different navigation tabs in another fragment.Then again i have to use actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);  but doing this will make Navigation tab of previous fragment also visible along with navigation tab of current fragment when switching from one fragment to another..check out my question for this..  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24908578/navigation-tab-of-previous-fragment-also-visible-when-switching-from-one-fragmen